# Host a sample page in my website from my computer?

Tags: web-services, web

I have registered a domain name. Now I want to host a sample html page to my domain and test it from my computer.

What i want to do is if I type www.mydomain.com then it should display a simple hello world page. I know I can do this by getting space form the web hosting providers and do that.

I just want to know how to do it from my own computer for testing purpose.

I have Windows XP. How to host from my computer using appache server. Step by step explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to test your website locally, then look into [easyphp](http://www.easyphp.org/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).
Both are very easy to setup and will allow you to run a local apache server and test your site as if it was live.

However if you want to use the domain name that you have registered, then you are going to need some hosting - you are not going to get anywhere just with a domain name and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to repoint the DNS entry for your domain at your home computer to do that (if you're on a fixed IP address), or use a service like DynDNS (if you don't have a fixed IP).

But if all you're after is testing with Apache etc. it would be far easier to simply install XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using no-ip for DNS. You can get a free one there and use their client to keep the ip forwarding updated. I used to run servers with their DNS, and you just have to confirm that you are still using it every month. Try searching google for setting up a web server on windows xp. You could probably find answers related to what you are trying to do.

Using their ip updating program will help you if your ip is not fixed.